Grand-total of the sum values in foreach loop
Since $total_amount shows the sum of the $entry values, I'm not sure how to go about adding the sum of all $total_amount and show it as $grand_total.
<table>
<?php
    $all_entry=json_decode($retrieved_data->income_entry);
    $total_amount=0;
    foreach($all_entry as $entry) {
        $total_amount+=$entry->amount;
    }

  <tr>
    <td><?php echo esc_html($retrieved_data->pay_method);?>:</td>
    <td><?php echo esc_html($total_amount);?></td>
  </tr>
?>
</table>
<p>Grand Total: <?php echo esc_html($grand_total);?></p>

The output to this code shows showing like this:
Cash: 15
Card: 37
Cash: 24
Cash: 12
Grand Total: 

I want the Grand Total to show as 88 but 15, 37, 24, 12 is already a sum of $entry and so I don't know how to add the sum and show the $grand_total.

Then you need to stop the PHP parser before you attempt to output HTML or ECHO the html inside a PHP syntax

And where are you accumulatinf $grand_total?

I think you want to place the 2 lines after the loop IN the loop and accumulate a $grand_total

It may well help if we saw an example of a couple of lines from the JSON file

@RiggsFolly Actually this is a simplified code and there's no code for $grand_total yet. I'm confused as to how to even begin as there is already $total_amount doing the sum.

@RiggsFolly I'm not sure how the JSON file is but it's not loading in the Chrome Network tab when I do inspect element and refresh the page.

Is all of this in another loop? (guessing from the multiple payment methods) If so, you want the $grand_total initialized before the outer loop, added to inside (same place you're doing the total_amount), and output after the outer loop.

Its loading in PHP and that is not shown in the Browser debugger. thats debugging Javascript code

@aynber Could you please help with the code demo? Thank You.

Topically related: Create new elements in a 2d array to hold row totals, column totals, and grand total

There are a couple of nuaunces to the output you are missing.
Output the individual price inside the loop, while accumulating the GrandTotal. The output the GrandTotal outside the loop
<table>
<tbody>
<?php
    $all_entry=json_decode($retrieved_data->income_entry);
    $total_amount = 0;
    foreach($all_entry as $entry) {
        $total_amount += $entry->amount;

        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>';
                echo esc_html($retrieved_data->pay_method);
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td>';
                echo esc_html($entry->amount); 
            echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
</tbody>
</table>

<p>Grand Total: <?php echo esc_html($total_amount);?> </p>

You may want to put the Grand Total in the table so you might consider this instead of the paragraph line after the table
Replace
?>
</tbody>
</table>

<p>Grand Total: <?php echo esc_html($total_amount);?> </p>

With

echo '<tr><td>Grand Total:</td><td>' . esc_html($total_amount) . '</td></tr>';
?>
</tbody>
</table>


I tried the code and looked at your code further. I must keep the existing code as it is and cannot remove $total_amount. Grand Total of all $entry is also okay since it's basically the same but without removing $total_amount. Thank you once again for your time and effort. Currently, your code shows only the last value (sum of $entry) in the loop.
